# Tools and best practice for reporting/presentation database

Tags: database-design

Currently my employer has a team that creates tableau dashboards and another very large team that creates ad hoc and regular reporting for external clients.
Both of these teams pull data from many databases and other sources.  For each report they either create a script that lives on their machine, a stored proc that lives in a source database, sometimes a scheduled job on a jenkins instance, or manually copy and paste the results of a query.  It's a badly documented mess.

My solution, that will have the least impact on how they work, and cost to implement, is to create a database on which all of the extracted data will live, so the reports and dashboards only access this single source.  A task scheduler to run regular extraction jobs, and a fairly simple custom software application that tracks changes to the source databases and alerts the project owners (of the jobs) but can also be used by the database owners to determine which downstream jobs will be impacted by changes to their databases.

I was wondering if what I have described already exists as a concept (is a presentation database a thing?) or if there exists software that could do the bulk of the heavy lifting for me? I after any tools that I might look into as alternatives, or concepts that might help my better design this solution.

---

So data needs to be extracted mainly from mssql, jira, jenkins and few custom sources.  I'd be storing the extracts on RDS and running the jobs once migrated on Jenkins.  I'd be building a custom web based UI for some very specific interactions, but monitoring would all be tableau dashboards.

The RDS instance wouldn't be a true data warehouse or vault, more akin to a lake I guess, as the data stored there would be aggregated from the disparate systems for a very specific purpose per table and would not be linked to each other in anyway.  This is basically replacing a huge number of regular extracts living all over the various systems and disks and instead storing them in a single database.

So I'm wondering in particular if this setup is common? and if there are any tools I should be looking at that might do some of this already.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referring to a concept called a [data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).  Data Warehousing is a huge topic, with a few main types of architecture: star schema, snowflake, and data vault. Googling these might give you some ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

May be it is helpful if you provide the names of the source systems you are extracting the data from .and also what platform do you have access to? where is this new database is going to be hosted/housed? DWman has already told you the perfect place to store this data-in the [data warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/synapse-analytics/?&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMI8aH0ydCJ6QIVg4TICh2pZwwKEAAYASAAEgJTFvD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2000128_SEM_Z27iY60H&MarinID=Z27iY60H_394526401093_sql%20data%20warehouse_e_c__46727496712_kwd-320563476154&lnkd=Google_Azure_Nonbrand&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8aH0ydCJ6QIVg4TICh2pZwwKEAAYASAAEgJTFvD_BwE).

If you have access to cloud services like aws or azure and if you are planning to house the database in azure ,you will get free tools for data extraction from the sources , transforming the data into a final format , that is how you want to see it in your reports and store it in a single place (the data warehouse). your solutions is a prefect answer to the problem!. you just have to put together the right tools to achieve it.

1. Well basically a Data warehouse is like any other database except that the data is in a different [Star or snowflake schema](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/star-schema-in-data-warehouse-modeling)  ,though i am not very expert with RDS systems , i know that it houses [Microsoft sql server](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver) . so what that means for you is you can house the database([data warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-collection/management-data-warehouse?view=sql-server-ver15) in RDS and you will get ETL tools for free i.e Sql server data tools(SSDT) and with SSDT you should be able to leverage existing code your report developers were using to extract data from the different source systems  with little or no modification . you can also get free report authoring and distribution services such as Microsoft sql server reporting services or power bi for free with the same license. but this all set up and management is going to require some skill in several Microsoft business intelligence tools ([Microsoft BI stack]